# How to use collect in Laravel 5.3?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, collect

I need use collect in Laravel 5.3 but I need help.

For Example:

```
$collection = collect([
  'Apple' => [
      ['name' => 'iPhone 6S', 'price' => '200'],
      ['name' => 'iPhone 7S', 'price' => '250'],
  ],
  'Samsung' => [
      ['name' => 'Galaxy S7', 'price' => '300']
      ['name' => 'Galaxy note', 'price' => '150']
  ],
]);
```

1. How to get `Apple` or `Samsung` name with collect? I need get brand name.
2. How to get (name and price) the cheapest price of each brand.

Thank you :-)

Comment: Did you refer the docs?

Comment: Hi @curious_coder , Yes, but to my question, I did not find the answer!

Comment: Can you show what your desired output would be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could achieve that through mapWithKeys

```
/* First get the minimum price */

$min = $collection->flatten(1)->pluck('price')->min();

/* Then perform the filteration */

$final = $collection->mapWithKeys(function($value, $key) use ($min) {
    $result = collect($value)->filter(function($inner) use ($min){
        return $inner['price'] === $min;
    })->keys()->first();

    return $result ? [$key => $value[$result]]: [];
});
```

When you run the above code, you will get

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
            [Samsung] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Galaxy note
                    [price] => 150
                )

        )

)
```

Now to get brand name simply do

```
$final->keys()->first() // Samsung
```

To get model name

```
$final->pluck('name')->first() // Galaxy note
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to use each to go through the outer array and min in the inner one to get the min price.  You'd then have to search to find the index and go back and use that to get the name/price.  At that rate, you're probably best off writing your own function that reads more nicely.

```
$collection->each(function ($item, $brand) {
    $minPrice = $item->min('price');
    $minIndex = $item->search(function ($item) use ($minPrice) { 
        return $item['price'] == $minPrice
    });
    echo $brand.' '.$item[$minIndex]['name']. ' '.$item[$minIndex]['price'];
});
```

You may have to collect on the inner items as I can't remember if collect automatically nests all the collections